# Is an expression 'at the top of my lung' used very commonly?

Tags: expressions

is it common to use an expresson  'at the top of my lung'  in english speaking countries? For example like 'I yelled at the top of my lung to get the attention of the man'

Comment: Yes, it is at least in the U.S.A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however, the expression is *at the top of my lungs,* where lungs is plural.

Comment: ...because most people have two lungs, of course.

Comment: I guess if a person didn't have both lungs, it would be correct to say lung.

Comment: Technically yes, but since it is a set phrase, probably not. It just explains why *lungs* is plural.